# Placing a dynamic text box inside a button, Flash As3, causes big error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

the button and text box haven't been added dynamically.

I have a movieclip with the instance name slot1.

Inside slot1 I have a button called newBtn1.

Inside new Btn1 I have a dynamic text box with the name text 1.

```
slot1.newBtn1.text1.text = "Button";
```

//this code gives me an error

```
                try 
                {
                    slot1.newBtn1.text1.text = "New Game";
                } 
                catch (err:Error) 
                {
                    trace(err);
                }
                slot1.newBtn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooceCharacter)
```

this is the error below

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property text1 not found on flash.display.SimpleButton and there is no default value.
```

This would work in As2 I am quite sure, but As3 is strict.

I'm using Flash CC and Flash Develop to code btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Short Version**

If the TextField is the only thing in your button then

```
TextField (slot1.newBtn1.upState).text = "New Game";
```

**The Long Version**

You cannot access the TextField that way because a SimpleButton is not a dynamic class like a MovieClip. You can have a read at [Dynamic classes in Flash](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f89.html). Let's say you have a object with the instance name "myobj" and you add this object to both a MovieClip and a Sprite. Here is how you might access each object.

```
MovieClip is dynamic
mymovieclip.myobj;

Sprite is not dynamic
mysprite.getChildByName ("myobj");
```

Another thing is that the SimpleButton is not a DisplayObjectContainer like the Flash IDE would lead you to believe. It has the properties `upState overState downState hitTestState` that are used to display the button. So when you draw something in the Up frame of a button in the IDE, the `upState` property will be set to a Shape instance. If you place a MovieClip in the Up frame, the `upState` will be that MovieClip, and so on.

So if you want to get to the object, you have to do so through the state properties. In your case you have a TextField in the Up frame so you must access it this way

```
slot1.newBtn1.upState;  //this will return a DisplayObject
TextField (slot1.newBtn1.upState);  //this will cast it so you can use it
```

Comment: Beautiful answer, short and long, many thanks! :D 

I have learnt something valuable, and thank you for the link you have posted.

Further reading!